# Firebird query giving weird results

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a table with two fields defined as varchar(15). I want to know which records have the same value in both fields:

```sql
 select * from table where field1 = field2
```

this returns a null result though I know there are records that match.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What Firebird version and OS, what is the full DDL of the table and all indexes?

Comment: Also be aware that in comparing varchar to varchar whitespace *is* significant (contrary to comparing char to char or varchar to char)

Comment: @Mark, perhaps I misunderstand, but trailing spaces are ignored when comparing a CHAR or VARCHAR to a CHAR or VARCHAR in FB.  See [here](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq237/).  That is, trailing whitespace is _not_ significant in this example.

Comment: I just tested it, and you are right trailing spaces are never significant with equals, so my comment was wrong. I do think this is wrong for VARCHAR to VARCHAR comparison, but I will need to check the SQL standard on this.

Comment: According to SQL standart shorter string appended with trailing spaces up to length of longer string while comparing.

Answer (score 2):

Without further information (see my comments), the problem might be a corrupted index. What happens when you try:

```
select * from table where field1 || '' = field2 || ''
```

Using this query will make Firebird ignore the index (if any) and do a full table scan.

If this does return a result, you will want to validate and maybe repair the database (using [gfix](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/gfix.html)) and either backup and restore the database or drop and recreate the index.